# How to create riak bucket type remotely from a client?

Tags: erlang, riak

The official manual tells about using console `riak-admin` to create bucket types.

But I would like to create bucket types directly from my client (it's an erlang app) on a remote cluster.
Is this somehow possible?

P.S. why would I need this? Nice for testing and migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [set_bucket_type/3](https://github.com/basho/riak-erlang-client/blob/master/src/riakc_pb_socket.erl#L583) ?

Like

```
riakc_pb_socket:set_bucket_type(Pid, <<"my_type">>, [{n_val, 10}]).
```